# Advantages of BTree+ over BTree

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [B- trees, B+ trees difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870218/b-trees-b-trees-difference)

What are the advantages/disadvantages of BTree+ over BTree? When should I prefer one over other? I'm also interested in knowing any real world examples where one has been preferred over other.

Comment: Looks like a real question to me.

Comment: Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870218/b-trees-b-trees-difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870218/b-trees-b-trees-difference)

Comment: Is a BTree+ the same thing as a B+tree?  Or yet another variation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article about [BTree+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree), this kind of data structure is frequently used for indexing block-oriented storage.  Apparently, BTree+ stored keys (and not values) are stored in the intermediate nodes.  This would mean that you would need fewer intermediate node blocks and would increase the likelihood of a cache hit.

Real world examples include various file systems; see the linked article.