# What are the differences between B-tree and B*-tree, except the requirement for fullness?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

I know about [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870218/b-trees-b-trees-difference) question, but it's about [**B-tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and [**B+-tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree). Sorry, if there's similar for `B*-tree`, but I couldn't find such.

---

So, what is the difference between these two trees? The [**wikipedia article**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B*-tree) about `B*-trees` is very short.

The only difference, that is noted there, is `"non-root nodes to be at least 2/3 full instead of 1/2"`. But I guess there's something more.. There could be just one kind of tree - the `B-tree`, just with different constants (for the fullness of each non-root node), and no two different trees, if this was the only difference, right?

Also, one more thing, that made me thing about more differences:

```
"A B*-tree should not be confused with a B+ tree, which is one where the 
leaf nodes of the tree are chained together in the form of a linked list"
```

So, `B+-tree` has something really specific - the linked list. What is the specific characteristic of `B*-tree`, or there isn't such?

---

Also, there are no any external links/references in the wikipedia's article. Are there any resources at all? Articles, tutorials, anything?

Thanks!

Comment: "Not a real question" ? What is the "not real" part here?

Comment: can you give a bit of context? if there's so little info about B*-trees, how did you become interested in them? a) out of curiosity, but also b) because it may help people think into the right direction

Comment: I haven't said, that "there's so little info about B*-trees". Short wikipedia article doesn't mean that there's no info in the net and that these trees are unfamiliar. Also, I don't think, that the reason I'm interested in B*-trees is important.. :) Anyway. I'm just learning advanced data structures and I didn't note any other differences, than the different fullness. And I wanted to ask for some help :) We're here for that, right?

Comment: didn't mean to criticize the fact that you're asking. just had the intuition that if there's a particular use case, you might get additional answers. happens often to me: "no idea what that's... oh that's what he's talking about". nevermind :)

Comment: You're right, but no - no other information. Just out of curiosity (:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edited**
No difference other than min. fill factor.

Page #489

[image: The Great Book]
<sub>(source: [mit.edu](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/9780262033848.jpg))</sub>

From the above book,

> **B-tree*** is a variant of a B-tree that requires each internal node to be at least 2/3 full, rather than at least half full.

Knuth also defines the B* tree exactly like that (The art of computer programming, Vol. 3).

"[The Ubiquitous B-Tree](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/356770.356776)" has a whole sub-section on **B-trees***. Here, Comer defines the **B-tree*** tree exactly as Knuth and Corment et al. do but also clarifies where the confusion comes from --**B-tree*** tree search algorithms and some unnamed B tree variants designed by Knuth which are now called **B<sup>+</sup>-*trees***.

Comment: please at least give a brief paraphrasing of the content there, otherwise the answer is not useful to anyone not owning this book

Comment: @Simon: that said, it's an excellent book, even though the maths are sometimes daunting oO

Comment: I'm asking about B*, not B+ ;p

Comment: Thanks, now you get +1 from me (:

Comment: @Monster TrucK: +1. Thanks for taking the time! This is an awesome example of the SO community working just as intended :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at Ubiquitous B-Tree by Comer (ACM Computing Surveys, 1979).

Comer writes there something about the B*Tree (In the section B-Tree and its variants). And in that section, he also cites some more paper about that topic. That should help you to do further investigations on your own :)! (I'm not your researcher ;) )

However, I don't understand the point where you cite a part which says that the B*Tree does not have a linked list in the leaf node level. I'm pretty sure, that also those nodes are linked together.

Regarding having only one B-Tree. Actually, you have that. The other ones like B+Tree, Prefix B+Tree and so on are just variants of the standard B-Tree. Just look at the paper Ubiquitous B-Tree.

Comment: Not yet. +1 from me for pointing me to the paper. I'll read it later, as I can't now. And no, I didn't post here, to find a "researcher", but just to ask someone to point me to some papers/tutorials/implementations/etc, as I already noted in my question ;)