# B+ tree or B-tree

Tags: postgresql, indexing, b-tree

I am learning about postgresql internals and I am wondering or postgresql B-tree index is actually classic B-tree or B+tree? To spell it out, that means the nodes contain only keys or key-value pairs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I said B-trees, first, but it's arguably closer to B+ trees.
See [iwis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67252824/939860) discussing it more thoroughly.

You would really have to consider index + heap (+ auxiliary storage) together. An index is mostly useless on its own.

Here is a [related chapter on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AB%2B_tree#PostgreSQL.27s_use_of_B.2B_trees).

The *name* of the relevant index method is "B-tree" in Postgres. Physical storage is very similar to that of tables (the heap) or any other index type. All use the same data pages with mostly the same page-layout. [More in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html)

Development is ongoing. The design has been changed (improved) in many aspects since this question was asked. The latest notable change (as of April 2021) being [deduplication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION) in Postgres 13.

Comment: but if db stores only keys it would be B+?

Comment: A b+ tree would store data in the leaves. The distinction between b and b+ tree does not make much sense for indexes to begin with. Index and table together form a special form of a b+ tree, if you will. The index itself is just a b-tree.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Do you mean that index in postgres are just a b-tree whose leaf node contains pointers to actual data stored in disk.

Comment: @a.m.: Something in between. The index contains the columns listed in the definition plus a pointer to the row, which is the complete "value".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : Thanks for clearing, If possible for you Can you please ans 1 of my que(kind of related/similar)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662145/why-there-is-a-performance-difference-between-single-column-select-and-multi-col/25674646#25674646

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Doesn't this make it still a B+-tree if you consider the pointer to the row data as well? (Which I would because the pointer is not a key...)

Comment: @r0estir0bbe: It's hard to draw the line. The distinction between "key" and "value" is not clear to begin with. What's a "key" to one query is the "value" to another. And there are also index-only scans, which use the index in B+ tree fashion, obviously. The classic use case is that the index stores keys and points to rows in the table holding values.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: To me, your answer sounds very cut/black & white - that is the reason why I was confused. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: the discussion about 'data' is confusing people and isn't significant.  The best way to understand the distinction is that in a naive b+tree, keys in internal nodes will be repeated in the leaves, while in a b-tree, if the key is stored in an internal node, it will not also be stored in a leaf.  It's absolutely the case that b+trees are often used as indicies where the 'data' portion is a reference to the full record.  The big advantage of a b+tree is simply that because everything is stored in leaves, you can make the leaves into a linked list and have very fast iteration of range queries.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: When Borys asked if the nodes also contain values, he meant whether non-leaf nodes contain pointers to records in the indexed table, because this is the difference between B-tree and B+ tree. It seems that non-leaf nodes don't have such pointers in PostgreSQL, so PostgreSQL seems to use B+ tree - please see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

It seems to me that PostgreSQL uses B+ tree.

### The difference between B-tree and B+ tree

- In B-tree the pointers to records in the indexed table are not only in the leaves of the tree, but also in all internal nodes of the tree.
- In B+ tree the pointers to records in the indexed table are only in the leaves of the tree. The advantages of B+ tree over B-tree are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870218/what-are-the-differences-between-b-trees-and-b-trees/).

[image: the picture is a modification]
(the picture is a modification of [this picture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014474/4592248))

### Usage of B+ tree in DBMSs

[Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, DB2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree), and [MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204561/does-mysql-use-b-tree-btree-or-both) use B+ tree. It seems that also PostgreSQL uses B+ tree because:

- The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/btree-implementation.html) seems to state that only the leaves of the tree have the pointers to records in the indexed table:

  > Each leaf page contains tuples that point to table rows. Each
  > internal page contains tuples that point to the next level down in the
  > tree.
- When Bruce Momjian [says](https://youtu.be/JFh22atXTRQ?t=5322) about internal nodes he doesn't mention that they have pointers to records in the indexed table.
- The *src/backend/access/nbtree/README* file of the PostgreSQL source code mentioned in the documentation contains this comment:

  > ### Btree Indexing
  >
  > This directory contains a correct implementation of Lehman and Yao's high-concurrency
  > B-tree management algorithm
  > (P. Lehman and S. Yao, [Efficient Locking for Concurrent Operations on B-Trees](https://www.csd.uoc.gr/%7Ehy460/pdf/p650-lehman.pdf),
  > ACM Transactions on Database Systems, Vol 6, No. 4, December 1981, pp 650-670).

  Lehman and Yao use a tree structure named *B* tree*, which was defined by Wedekind in [On the selection of access paths in a data base system](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221325577_On_the_Selection_of_Access_Paths_in_a_Data_Base_System) paper as B-tree where non-leaf nodes don't have pointers to records in the indexed table (they have pointers only to their children nodes). So the B* tree structure defined by Wedekind is a B+ tree.

Comment: I agree, the implementation is closer to a B+ tree. But the discussion does not make a whole lot of sense to begin with. You would really have to consider index and heap (and toast table and other auxiliaries) together.